# Parsing double values from JSON in Flutter and Dart

Tags: json, dart, flutter, double

I have problems while I try to get double values from JSON in Flutter.

```
class MapPoint {
  String title;
  double lat;
  double lng;

  MapPoint({this.title, this.lat, this.lng});

  factory MapPoint.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return MapPoint(
        title: json["title"] as String,
        lat: json["lat"] as double,
        lng: json["lng"] as double
    );
  }
}
```

For some reason I got error

> Dart Error: Unhandled exception: type 'double' is not a subtype of
>   type 'String'

I tried some to user `double.parse(json["lng"])` instead but got same error.
Same time this way of getting data from JSON works fine with other types.

This is JSON example

```
{ 
   point: {
     title: "Point title",
     lat: 42.123456,
     lng: 32.26567
  }
}
```

Comment: What JSON causes this error? If your values are wrapped in quotes, they won't be interpreted as double.

Comment: JSON is fine because I can get all other values (sting and int) from it

Comment: Either the JSON doesn't fit your code or your code doesn't fit your JSON. Without providing the JSON that causes the error you can as well delete the question because it just doesn't provide the required information to diagnose the issue.

Comment: I added example of JSON. One thing that can be unusual is that double values are not presented as strings.

Comment: That is not valid JSON. In JSON keys must be quoted and there is a `,` missing after `"Point title"`. Double values are never represented as `String` in JSON.

Comment: `,` was missed in example, sorry. What I mean by double as `String` in JSON - can be seen https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users where geo positions are inside qoutes

Comment: The quotes around the keys are still missing.

Answer (score 30):

The Dart JSON parser converts the property inside json and apparently is clever enough to spit a double type.

`someVariable as double` expects a String at the left side.

Whats probably happening is that you're trying to convert a double into a double.

I would try something like this:

```
lat: json["lat"].toDouble(),
```

This would cover the case of the data in your JSON comes like "5". In this case the dart json converter would cast the type to int and it would break your code if you are always expecting a double.

Comment: lat: double.parse(json["lat"])

Comment: If you are not sure whethe rthe type is int or double; better to declare it as `num`

Answer (score 8):

I was having the same problem, the way I think it was this:

```
class MapPoint {
  String title;
  double lat;
  double lng;

  MapPoint({this.title, this.lat, this.lng});

  factory MapPoint.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return MapPoint(
        title: json["title"] as String,
        lat: json["lat"] is int ? (json['lat'] as int).toDouble() : json['lat'],
        lng: json["lng"] is int ? (json['lng'] as int).toDouble() : json['lng']
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I have tried several ways, but this works :D

Answer (score 6):

Rewrite your `fromJson` method as follows:

```
factory MapPoint.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return MapPoint(
        title: json["title"] as String,
        lat : double.parse(json["lat"].toString()),
        lng : double.parse(json["lng"].toString()),
    );
  }
```

If your `lat` field is nullable, for example:

```
double? lat
```

In your `fromJson` method, instead of:

```
lat : double.parse(json["lat"].toString()),
```

Use:

```
lat : double.tryParse(json["lat"].toString()),
```

Comment: Hello @moonvader, please do consider on marking the answer as accepted, if it has helped to solve your problem (or to answer your question).

Answer (score 2):

I can not reproduce

```
void main() {
  final json = {
    "point": {"title": "Point title", "lat": 42.123456, "lng": 32.26567}
  };
  final p = MapPoint.fromJson(json);
  print(p);
}

class MapPoint {
  String title;
  double lat;
  double lng;

  MapPoint({this.title, this.lat, this.lng});

  factory MapPoint.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return MapPoint(
        title: json["title"] as String,
        lat: json["lat"] as double,
        lng: json["lng"] as double);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

i can fix this problem this way

```
class MapPoint {
  String title;
  double lat;
  double lng;

  MapPoint({this.title, this.lat, this.lng});

  factory MapPoint.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return MapPoint(
        title: json["title"] as String,
        lat: json["lat"] *1.0,
        lng: json["lng"] *1.0
    );
  }
}
```